# glutPassiveMotionFunc in Qt

Tags: qt, opengl, glut

I'm trying to make an 'fps' camera in OpenGL using Qt. I'm able to move the mouse and rotate the camera accordingly, the only problem I'm having is that I have to click and drag in order for it to happen (the mouseMoveEvent is only called when the mouse is being pressed). Now I've been searching around all day, and there is a lot of conflicting and outdated information about OpenGL on the internet. My question is really quite simple, does the QOpenGLWidget have some functionality similar to [glutPassiveMotionFunc](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node51.html), or do I have to install the glut library to get this functionality? Other suggestions to get this functionality (other, better documented libraries for example) are also welcome. In case I have to install the glut library, it would also be amazing if someone would have documented a proper way of doing this, because I seem to find a million different ways, all equally hard to understand.

Comment: Did you turn on the [`mouseTracking`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) on your `QOpenGLWidget`?

Comment: Wow, can't believe it was that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Qt doesn't handle simple mouse move events. It has to be turned on via the [`mouseTracking`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) property:

```
yourOpenGLWidget->setMouseTracking(true);
```